# summer21 lwc quick action feature doesn't show header with `lightning-quick-action-panel`

Tags: lightning-web-components

Header is not showing when i use `lightning-quick-action-panel` with [summer 21 lwc quickAction feature.](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions.html)

am i miss anything?

**lwcqademo.js-meta**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**lwcqademo.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-quick-action-panel title="Quick Action Demo">     
    <slot name="body">
        {recordId}</slot>
        
</lightning-quick-action-panel>
    
</template>
```

**lwcqademo.js**

```
import {CloseActionScreenEvent} from "lightning/actions";
export default class Lwcqademo extends LightningElement {
    //public properties
    @api recordId;
closeAction(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

replaced `title` with `header` for `lightning-quick-action-panel` then modal popup header is showing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, proper documentation.

Even though Salesforce blog post uses "title" the tag that works is actually "header". This is completely undocumented only because Summer 21 documentation is still not up weeks after the production release.

Comment: thank you, header is working as charm

Comment: Salesforce still haven't updated the doc, what a waste of time.